# How To Implement Drafting Symbols

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am looking specifically for the centerline symbol (looks like a C with an L overlaid on it).

Is anyone aware of a LaTeX package that might include common drafting symbols such as this?

Maybe I should just make one myself using TikZ?

Any other suggestions? I appreciate the input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe a stack:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\CL{\textsf{\stackengine{0.55ex}{C\,}{\,L}{U}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}
\begin{document}
Centerline is \CL
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, how neat. I have never heard or seen this package before! Thank you for sharing and the suggestion! I'll give it a try!

Comment: @Nukesub You can find it at http://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine.  Also, its companion package that can also do tabbed stacks, http://ctan.org/pkg/tabstackengine